# Column Brake on 4th Post

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm a noob to using Liquid and Jekyll.  I'm using them to manage content for a responsive Bootstrap template I'm creating for Github Pages.  On my homepage I am returning truncated summaries of my most recent six posts, three posts per column.

```
{% if content == nil %}
{% assign content = post.content %}
{% endif %}
          <h5>{{ post.title }}</h5>
          <p>{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 38 }} <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">Read more &raquo;</a></p>
```

I've been unsuccessful at finding a method to insert a "</div><div>" after the third result.  I've tried a Loop and a Cycle without luck.

Any help the community could provide this noob would be greatly appreciated.  I'm open sourcing this template on Github when I'm finished with it.

Answer (score 1):

`cycle` should work:

```
{% cycle '', '', '', '</div><div>' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through post.content with an for-loop, you can use  forloop.index or forloop.index0 to determine if the current iteration can be divided by three and insert the `</div><div>`.

Check out http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid#For_loops

Answer (score 0):

this should work (it does for first, so why not third!)

```
{% if forloop.third %}
<aside class="ad">
    <p>sponsored by...</p>
    <!-- ad stuff -->
</aside>
{% endif %}
```